macro should run ahed if msg box is not triggered
I want my macro to continue if the yes no msg box is not triggered.
currently i have set a yes no msg box in my macro. for example if the value in cell A1 is more than 100 then the msg box pops up and says "the value is above 100, do you wish to continue?" if i press no it exits sub and if i press yes the rest of the code executes. cool everything works good, but the issue is, when the value in cell A1 is less than 100 and i run the macro, just nothing happens. i want the macro to continue also if the value in cell A1 is below 100.
thank you
i am using the following code for msg box
Sub Relieving_Pdf()
    Dim AnswerYes As String
    Dim AnswerNo As String
    Dim StrFolder As String
    Dim StrFile As String
    Dim Folder As String
    Dim StrName As String
    Dim StrBack1 As String
    Dim StrBack As String

    StrFolder = Range("A69").Value 'path
    StrFile = Range("B28").Value  'Company Initial Name
    Folder = "\" & Range("F1").Text   'Month and year folder name
    StrName = "\" & Range("B2").Value   'Candidate name
    StrBack1 = Left$(StrFolder, InStrRev(StrFolder, "\") - 1)
    StrBack = Left$(StrBack1, InStrRev(StrBack1, "\") - 1)

    Application.Run "REFRESH"

    If Range("E14").Value = "EID Already Exist" Then
        AnswerYes = MsgBox("EID Already Exist Do you want to go ON?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "User Repsonse")
        If AnswerYes = vbYes Then
            If Len(Dir(StrBack & Folder, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then

                MkDir(StrBack & Folder)
            End If
            If Len(Dir(StrBack & Folder & StrName, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then

                MkDir(StrBack & Folder & StrName)
            End If
            ChDir StrFolder
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
                StrFolder & "\" & StrFile & " Master Data.xlsm", _
                FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            Dim excelpath As String
            Dim wordApp As Object
            Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
            excelpath = ThisWorkbook.FullName
            wordApp.Documents.Open Filename:=StrFolder & "\" & StrFile & " Master File Macro.docm"
            wordApp.Visible = True
            ActiveDocument.MailMerge.OpenDataSource Name:= _
                excelpath _
                , ConfirmConversions:=False, ReadOnly:=False, LinkToSource:=True, _
                AddToRecentFiles:=False, PasswordDocument:="", PasswordTemplate:="", _
                WritePasswordDocument:="", WritePasswordTemplate:="", Revert:=False, _
                Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, Connection:= _
                "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;Data Source=excelpath;Mode=Read;Extended Properties=""HDR=YES;IMEX=1;"";Jet OLEDB:System database="""";Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="""";Jet OLEDB:Engi" _
                , SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `Output$`", SQLStatement1:="", SubType:= _
                wdMergeSubTypeAccess      'enter sheet name
            ActiveDocument.MailMerge.ViewMailMergeFieldCodes = wdToggle

            With ActiveDocument.MailMerge
                .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
                .SuppressBlankLines = True
                With .DataSource
                    .FirstRecord = 1
                    .LastRecord = 1
                    StrName2 = "\" & .DataFields("offername")
                    StrFolder = StrBack & "\"
                End With
                ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
                    StrFolder & Folder & StrName & StrName2 & ".pdf", ExportFormat:= _
                    wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=False, OptimizeFor:= _
                    wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=wdExportFromTo, From:=1, To:=4, Item:= _
                    wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, _
                    CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
                    BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False
            End With

            ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
            wordApp.Quit
            Set wdapp = Nothing
            Application.Quit
        End If
    End If
End Sub


So you want your code to continue whether the value is above or below 100, and regardless if the user selects Yes or No?

no... say 1st situation - if the value in cell A1 is less than 100, its okay the macro can continue. 2nd situation - if the value in cell A1 is more than 100 it gives a yes no msg box and i click yes and macro can continue. 3rd situation - if the value in cell A1 is more than 100 it gives a yes no msg box and i click No, the macro stops.

Do you have a VBA project reference added in Excel for the Word object library? If not then Excel VBA doesn't know the value of constants such as wdExportFromTo, wdDoNotSaveChanges etc.  And ActiveDocument should probably be wordApp.ActiveDocument

@SamySomy - Your code and your description of the problem don't align 100%. Can you please fix it or explain why?

first yes i have added the word object library and second my code and the description of the problem don't align 100% beacuse all my code was working all perfect without the yes no msg box, later on when i started getting issues with my document (i.e duplicate employee code) i decided to put a yes no msg box. previously i had just had a warning msg box that would warn me that i have entered an already used Ecode, but sometimes i need to keep going on with same Ecode even if it is already used.

let me explain
if i enter a Ecode say "123" in B3, The cell E14 will populate either "EID Already Exist" or just blank "".
my requirement.

If the Ecode "123" is never used before then macro should keep going.
if the E code "123" is used before it will give a yes / no.
If i still want to go with Ecode "123" then i click YES and the macro should keep going.
I dont want to go with Ecode "123" then i click NO and macro stops.

thats all i want

The code I posted only runs when E14 = "EID Already Exists", and it only exits the sub if the user doesn't click Yes when prompted.  Pretty sure that matches what you asked for.

not exactly tim, i tried that code and it was the same situation as before but Vbasic2008's solution i working for me perfectly

Compare Strings

The following tool should help you figure out what's going on, i.e., whether you have a typo (incl. case-sensitivity) or are in the correct cell, worksheet, and workbook.
At first run it as is. Once it runs as required, implement it in your code.

Sub Test()
    
    Const CELL_ADDRESS As String = "E14"
    Const COMPARE_STRING As String = "EID Already Exists" ' changed (English)!!!
    Const SHOW_COMPARISON_EVALUATION_MESSAGE As Boolean = True
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    Dim CellString As String: CellString = CStr(ws.Range(CELL_ADDRESS).Value)
    
    ' This is a case-insensitive comparison i.e. 'A = a'
    Dim AreStringsEqual As Boolean: AreStringsEqual _
        = (StrComp(CellString, COMPARE_STRING, vbTextCompare) = 0)
    
    If SHOW_COMPARISON_EVALUATION_MESSAGE Then
        MsgBox "The value in cell ""'" & ws.Name & "!'" & CELL_ADDRESS _
            & """ of workbook """ & ws.Parent.Name & """ is """ _
            & CellString & """." & vbLf _
            & "You are comparing it with the given string """ _
            & COMPARE_STRING & """." & vbLf & vbLf _
            & "The result is that they are """ _
            & IIf(AreStringsEqual, "", "NOT ") & "EQUAL""!", _
            IIf(AreStringsEqual, vbInformation, vbExclamation), _
            "Comparison Evaluation"
    End If
    
    Dim Answer As Long ' changed (there's only one)!!!
    
    If AreStringsEqual Then
        Answer = MsgBox( _
            Prompt:="EID already exists. Do you want to continue?", _
            Buttons:=vbQuestion + vbYesNo, _
            Title:="User Response")
        If Answer = vbNo Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
    
    MsgBox "Continuing...", vbInformation
    ' rest of the code

End Sub


Like this maybe?
'...
'...
Application.Run "REFRESH"

'this check is only triggered in a specific case
If Range("E14").Value = "EID Already Exist" Then
    ans = MsgBox("EID Already Exist Do you want to go ON?", _
                  vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "User Repsonse")

    If ans <> vbYes Then Exit Sub  'exit if user hasn't clicked Yes
End If

If Len(Dir(StrBack & Folder, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
    MkDir (StrBack & Folder)
End If
'...
'...rest of code



thanks for reply....tried this but the situation is same. nothing happens

Your posted code didn't match your description, so I went with the posted code.  Maybe there's some other issue with the code you didn't post?

...note for example you've not specified a specific worksheet to check for the value in E14, so it will default to the ActiveSheet.

yes i want it to search in active sheet only....i am posting the code

My Yes/No code should work in place of the code you posted.  If not then you will need to debug and find out where the issue is.

i have added the code in the question
